# Find window by title (with Wild cards) then focus that window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a little addon that when clicked will find a open window (This is in a company setting and will always be open) with a specific word in the title using wild cards `(*MAX*)`

fyi. i have very little knowledge on chrome inter workings.

iv'e tried to get all the current open windows and if the title == my search then update the window but with out susses

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

    chrome.windows.getAll({populate : true}, function (window_list) {
        var list = [];
        for(var i=0;i<window_list.length;i++) {

            // push to table to test         
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.innerHTML = window_list[i].id;
        }
    });
});
```

This gives me the ids of the windows but i want to get the titles and then if them, then use something like 
chrome.windows.update(windowid, {focused: true});
to bring it back to the front is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is a property of a [tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) object, not the [window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window) object.

You can use [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) directly with a title pattern:

```
chrome.tabs.query({title: '(*MAX*)'}, tabs => {
  if (!tabs.length) return;
  chrome.windows.update(tabs[0].windowId, {focused: true});
  chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {active: true});
});
```