# Open the same window opened from the popup.html when a button is clicked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension and a popup.html, This popup.html UI has a single button when clicked it would open a web page in the external popup window

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <article style="width: 34rem">
        <button id="open">Click to open the App</button>
    </article>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<body>
```

**The popup.js code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#open").click(function() {
        window.open("https://www.example.com",'The title','height=678,width=650').focus();
    });
});
```

The user clicks the button on popup.html and it opens a window and the new window gets focused (I have no problem with that), The new window can be minimized by the user when its not active.

Say a user minimized the new window and again clicks the button on the popup.html another instance of the new window is created.

I am looking for a way to open focus the same earlier minimized window instead of new. How do I achieve it?

Comment: [Find window by title (with Wild cards) then focus that window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58645348)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#open").click(function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({
            title: 'Your title name'
        }, tabs => {
            if (!tabs.length) {
                window.open("https://www.example.com", 'Your title name', 'height=678,width=650').focus();
                return;
            }
            chrome.windows.update(tabs[0].windowId, {
                focused: true
            });
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {
                active: true
            });
        });
    });
});
```